# custom sort using pred c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a vector lines and I created struct to sort for both x- and y-axes:

```
struct linesSort {
    bool operator() (Vec4i l1, Vec4i l2) {
        int x1 = l1[0];
        int y1 = l1[1];
        int x2 = l2[0];
        int y2 = l2[1];
        if (x1 == x2) return (y1 < y2);
        else return (x1 < x2);
    }
};
```

And then I call: `sort(lines.begin(), lines.end(), linesSort());`

The result is prety good EXCEPT some case that the 2 edges position of line had change to each other. such as:

```
[0, 328, 639, 272]
[0, 329, 1, 297]
[0, 347, 639, 291]
[0, 367, 639, 311]
[639, 311, 0, 368]
[0, 368, 639, 310]
[639, 310, 0, 369]
[639, 310, 0, 369]
[0, 387, 639, 331]
```

Where am I wrong ? please help !

Comment: *"the 2 edges position of line had change to each other."* What do you mean?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Like this? https://ideone.com/OixqAr *shrug*

Comment: @CinCout let me explain:
each line has two edge points: p1(line[0], line[1]) and p2(line[2], line[3]). 
I don't know why do they change to each other (p1 becomes p2 and p2 becomes p1) AFTER sorting. !?

Comment: Create a MCVE please

Comment: @RetiredNinja I can't see website ideone.com/OixqAr. Can you post it here ?

Comment: *...some case that the 2 edges position of line had change to each other* - Um.. what ? Lets try this again.

Comment: show the input and the expected output. We don't understand what you mean.